# How to sign a jar to never expire?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jar, jar-signing

I used `jarsigner` to sign my jar file. But I got a warning:

```
Warning:
This jar contains entries whose signer certificate will expire within six months.
```

How can I make it never expire or expire in a longer time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specify the required number of days in the `-validity` parameter to [`keytool`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html).

Addendum: `-validity` is an option to [`keytool`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html).

```
keytool -genkey -alias sawyer -validity 1234 -dname "…"
```

After you create the new key, use its unique alias with [`jarsigner`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html) to sign your JAR.

Comment: I didn't successfully used -validity option, in my jarsigner command, I cannot see an option parameter called -validity, and also please see here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419425/to-change-jar-expiry-time